# How do I create a bidirectional data binding in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, flex3

I need to bind a property to an edit control and have the control write its value back to the same property.  The problem is, I'm setting the source value *before* the control is created:

```
<mx:Panel>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable] public var editedDocument: XML;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:TextInput id="docLabel" text="{editedDocument.@label}"/>
    <mx:Binding source="docLabel.text" destination="editedDocument.@label"/>
</mx:Panel>
```

I call this like so:

```
var xmlDoc: XML = <document label="some label" />;
var myPanel: MyPanel = new MyPanel();
myPanel.editedDocument = xmlDoc;
parent.addChild(myPanel);
```

What happens is this:

- the docLabel text field ends up blank (equal to "")
- the xmlDoc's @label attribute is set to ""

What I *want* is this:

- the docLabel text field should contain "some label"
- the xmlDoc's @label attribute should change only when the docLabel's text property changes.

How do I accomplish this, using Flex 3?

**Edit**

I have also tried this:

```
<mx:Panel>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable] public var editedDocument: XML;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:TextInput id="docLabel"/>
    <mx:Binding source="editedDocument.@label" destination="docLabel.text"/>
    <mx:Binding source="docLabel.text" destination="editedDocument.@label"/>
</mx:Panel>
```

The result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using BindingUtils to programmatically create the binding after the class has been created:
http://life.neophi.com/danielr/2007/03/programmatic_bindings.html

There are many variations of this that I've used to tackle similar problems.  If you can't figure it out from the link post a comment and I'll dig through my source code and see what I can find.

```
private function init():void 
{
  var xmlDoc: XML = <document label="some label" />;
  var myPanel: MyPanel = new MyPanel();
  myPanel.editedDocument = xmlDoc;
  parent.addChild(myPanel);
  BindingUtils.bindProperty(docLabel, "text", editedDocument, "label");

  //or maybe it should be one of these, I have not done binding to an XML attribute before
  BindingUtils.bindProperty(docLabel, "text", editedDocument, "@label");
  BindingUtils.bindProperty(docLabel, "text", editedDocument, "{@label}");
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of the general use of BindingUtils, I just can't find the right order of calls to use to cause my code to act as I want it to.  Can you perhaps supply a simple, two-class bit of code that does just what I've got above?

Comment: I think the key is to add the BindingUtils programatically (not via MXML elements) after your initialization is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Two-way data binding](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Two-way+Data+Binding).
Take a look at the part of the text:

> In Flex 3, if you want to set
>   two-way binding using the
>
> mx:Binding

tag you need to set it twice: 
`mx:Binding source="a.property" destination="b.property"/>` 
`mx:Binding source="b.property" destination="a.property"/>`

which becomes:

```
mx:Binding source="a.property" destination="b.property" twoWay="true"/>
```

Comment: You probably didn't read the link.
In Flex 3, if you want to set two-way binding using the <mx:Binding> tag you need to set it twice:

<mx:Binding source="a.property" destination="b.property"/>
<mx:Binding source="b.property" destination="a.property"/>

which becomes:

<mx:Binding source="a.property" destination="b.property" twoWay="true"/>

A shame I would say!

Comment: Right.  I tried that, though, and it did the bindings in the wrong order, resulting in the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

In Flex 3 you would be better of doing something like this.  Also not sure you can bind directly to XML?

Instead do something like this:

```
        [Bindable] public var tmpString: String;


        public var onChange():void {
                tmpString = docLabel.text;
                //set the XML string, etc.
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:TextInput id="docLabel" text="{tmpString}" change="onChange()" />
```

Comment: You can bind directly to XML. The curly brackets can contain any valid AS expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think bidirectional data binding is a new feature in Flex 4.

Comment: No, bidirectional data binding is very much possible in Flex 3. A *shortcut to create* bidirectional data binding is a *proposed* feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from Adboe http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Two-way+Data+Binding, and it's Flex 3 too!

Comment: Actually, no, it's a description of the Flex 4 binding specification.

Answer (score 0):

I created custom controls that programmatically create two-way bindings when given a provider object that has a suitable property whose name matches the control's id. Here's an example for a `TextInput`:

```
public class BoundTextInput extends TextInput
{
  // some code omitted for brevity:
  // Create getter / setter pair, call invalidateProperties()
  // and set internal flag for efficiency

  // create bindings in commitProperties:
  override protected function commitProperties():void
  {
    if (this._fProviderChanged) {
      this._fProviderChanged = false;
      if (null != this._provider && this._provider.hasOwnProperty(this.id) && this._provider[this.id] is String) {
        // this is the core bit
        BindingUtils.bindProperty(this, "text", this._provider, this.id);
        BindingUtils.bindProperty(this._provider, this.id, this, "text");
      }
    }
    // Normally, you call the overridden method first,
    // but we want to see the values initialized by the new
    // binding right away, so we first create the bindings
    // and then commit all inherited properties
    super.commitProperties();
}
```

}

This is an example of how I use it inside one of my other components (a popup dialog). The `data` property is set to an instance of the appropriate model class, which is always a dumb, `[Bindable]` container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PopUp xmlns="com.econemon.suite.gui.components.*" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Form width="100%" height="100%" >
    <mx:FormHeading label="Server-URL" />
    <mx:FormItem label="URL" >
      <!--
        If it is available, and of type String, data.urlServer
        is bound to the text property of this TextInput
      -->
      <BoundTextInput id="urlServer" provider="{this.data}"/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem>
      <mx:Button label="OK" click="this.submit(event)" />
    </mx:FormItem>
  </mx:Form>
</PopUp>
```